# Can not hide div after mouseout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to make something like Twitter's author pane: When a `dropdown` area is hovered on, a box containing the user info is appended to `atuhor-pane` and on mouse out, the box disappears.

```js
$(".dropdown").hover(function() {
  let athrDiv = $(this).children(".author-pane");
  let box = `<div class="box">I'm John'Doe's info box </div>`;
  athrDiv.empty();
  athrDiv.append(box);
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '.dropdown', function() {
  $(this).children(".box").empty();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.box {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <strong class="author">John Doe</strong>

  <div class="author-pane">
  </div>
</div>

<div>Lorem ibsum</div>
```

The problem is two fold

1. The box does not disappear after mouseout.
2. The box does not appear OVER the page (without displacing the next div)

How can I fix these?

Comment: 1. `$(this).children(".box")` does not find the element - because `$(this)` refers to the `.dropdown` element, but `.box` is not actually a _child_ of that. You want to use `.find()` instead of `.children()`. 2. Absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `css` only as well. Simply `display` `none` & `block` on hover.

```
.author:hover + .author-pane{display:block;}
```

```js
$(".dropdown").hover(function() {
  let athrDiv = $(this).children(".author-pane");
  let box = `<div class="box">I'm John'Doe's info box </div>`;
  athrDiv.empty();
  athrDiv.append(box);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.author-pane {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: -203px;
  top: 0px;
}

.dropdown:hover .author-pane {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <strong class="author">John Doe</strong>

  <div class="author-pane">
  </div>
</div>

<div>Lorem ibsum</div>
```

Comment: Sounds good. But what about the second issue. I'd like the box to appear OVER the page, not pushing the next div down.

Comment: use css position absolute - that will do.

Comment: When I add `position: absolute;` to `.box` nothing changes. please update your answer.

Comment: I need to be able to move mouse into the box before it disappears.

Comment: check the updated answer i hover on dropdown instead of author and that will solve your issue.

Comment: Great. So you don't need the `mouseout` part. Please remove it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass two functions to hover event
1. for showing details on hover in
2. for deleting details on hover out

Also, use `$(function(){...}` to ensure DOM is loaded fully and your jquery script is getting all required elements

```js
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(function () {
      let athrDiv = $(this).children(".author-pane");
      let box = `<div class="box">I'm John'Doe's info box </div>`;       
      athrDiv.empty();
      athrDiv.append(box);
   }, function(){
      let athrDiv = $(this).children(".author-pane");      
      athrDiv.empty();
   });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
      <strong class="author">John Doe</strong>

              <div class="author-pane">
              </div>
 </div>
 <div>Lorem ibsum</div>
```

Comment: It's obscure to me how does the second function work?

Answer (score 0):

It's because mouseover takes care of mouse enter & leave events.
Check out [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/hover) documentation:

> Bind one or two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer ***enters and leaves*** the elements.

You should point out the actions you want per event:

```
$(".dropdown").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      let athrDiv = $(this).children(".author-pane");
      let box = `<div class="box">I'm John'Doe's info box </div>`;
      athrDiv.empty();
      athrDiv.append(box);    
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).find(".author-pane").empty();    
    }
}
);
```